# How to get elements with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, class, element

Say I have this:

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
```

How do I select this `div` element?

```
document.getElementsByClassName('class1')[0].getElementsByClassName('class2')[0]
```

That does not work.

I know that, in jQuery, it is `$('.class1.class2')`, but I'd like to select it with vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 375):

**AND** *(both classes)*

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("class1 class2");
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".class1.class2");
```

**OR** *(at least one class)*

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".class1,.class2");
```

**XOR** *(one class but not the other)*

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".class1:not(.class2),.class2:not(.class1)");
```

**NAND** *(not both classes)*

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(":not(.class1),:not(.class2)");
```

**NOR** *(not any of the two classes)*

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(":not(.class1):not(.class2)");
```

Comment: `var list = document.querySelector('.remove_fields.dynamic, .remove_fields.existing')`

To get the `element` if it has any of the combination is present but not both.

Comment: I just want to add something along with every other answers. If you want to select elements of specific tag type, for examle `<img>`, that belongs to mulitple classes then you can specify the tag name along with the class names in `querySelectorAll()` in the following format `document.querySelectorAll("tagname.class1.class2.class3")`

Answer (score 235):

It's actually very similar to jQuery:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('class1 class2')
```

[MDN Doc getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: what about getting element with only one class , which is the one specified @Joe

Comment: as I remember the classes comes without "."  document.getElementsByClassName('class1 class2')

Comment: In the given MDN link, dot is not used before class names in getElements parameter. I checked this on firefox as well as chrome and it worked without dots, but not with dots.

Answer (score 52):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with standard class selectors also works for this.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.class1.class2');
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it needs to be 
`document.querySelectorAll('.class1, .class2');`

Comment: @bazzlebrush your selector would capture elements with `.class1` OR `.class2`, while the one above would only capture elements with *both* classes and does in fact work. See the console output of this test: https://jsfiddle.net/0ph1p9p2/

Comment: Ok, my bad, I misunderstood what the OP wanted to do. But IMO a more typical use case is to want to select elements which have either class or both, in which case my example is what you want.

Answer (score 22):

As @filoxo said, you can use `document.querySelectorAll`.

If you know that there is only one element with the class you are looking for, or you are interested only in the first one, you can use:

```
document.querySelector('.class1.class2');
```

BTW, while `.class1.class2` indicates an element with *both* classes, `.class1 .class2` (notice the whitespace) indicates an hierarchy - and element with class `class2` which is inside en element with class `class1`:

```
<div class='class1'>
  <div>
    <div class='class2'>
      :
      :
```

And if you want to force retrieving a direct child, use `>` sign (`.class1 > .class2`):

```
<div class='class1'>
  <div class='class2'>
    :
    :
```

For entire information about selectors:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Answer (score 2):

Okay this code does exactly what you need:

HTML:

```
<div class="class1">nothing happens hear.</div>

<div class="class1 class2">This element will receive yout code.</div>

<div class="class1">nothing happens hear.</div>
```

JS:

```
function getElementMultipleClasses() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("class1 class2");
    x[0].innerHTML = "This is the element you want";
}
getElementMultipleClasses();
```

Hope it helps! ;)

Answer (score 1):

***html***

```
<h2 class="example example2">A heading with class="example"</h2>
```

***javascritp code***

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll(".example.example2");
element.style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

**The querySelectorAll() method returns all elements in the document that matches a specified CSS selector(s), as a static NodeList object.**

**The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.**

also learn more about https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

== Thank You ==

Answer (score 0):

actually @bazzlebrush 's answer and @filoxo 's comment helped me a lot.

I needed to find the elements where the class could be "zA yO" **OR** "zA zE"

Using jquery I first select the parent of the desired elements:

(a div with class starting with 'abc' and style != 'display:none')

```
var tom = $('div[class^="abc"][style!="display: none;"]')[0];
```

then the desired children of that element:

```
var ax = tom.querySelectorAll('.zA.yO, .zA.zE');
```

works perfectly! note you don't have to do document.querySelector you can as above pass in a pre-selected object.