# Why does my submenu overlap another child element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day to all! I am facing an overlap issue when opening a submenu. If you open the first section and open the second submenu tab, the content that comes from 1 tab does not close and overlaps with second tab. How to make it so that when you click on the second title, the first one is hidden? Thanks for helping!

[image]

Code:

```js
var nav = document.querySelector('.nav-component');
var menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
var menuItem = document.querySelector('.menu-item');
var itemOpened = document.querySelector('.item-opened');

menuToggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nav.classList.toggle('open');
  document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item.item-opened').forEach(openitem => {
    openitem.classList.remove('item-opened');
  });
  document.querySelectorAll('.chevron').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
      document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item.item-opened').forEach(openitem => {
        openitem.classList.remove('item-opened');
      });
      item.classList.toggle('item-opened');
    })
  })
}, false);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

a {text-decoration: none;color: #fff;}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0 0 18px;
}
p span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 2px 4px;
}
p span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -12px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 0 0 3px;
}
p span:after {
  content: '';
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -6px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 6px 8px 6px;
  border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}


h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  font-size:18px;
}

button {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 24px;
  right: 20px;
  border: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left:50%;
  right: 0;
  background: blue;
  zoom: 1.2;
}
button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(burger.svg) no-repeat;background-size: contain;
}
button:after {
  opacity: 1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 0;
  background: url(close.svg) no-repeat;background-size: contain;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
}
button:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(2px);
          transform: translateY(2px);
}
button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.open button {
  opacity: 1;
}
.open button:before {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}
.open button:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(360deg);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.4s 1s ease-out, opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.4s 1s ease-out, opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
}

nav {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #776968;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.open nav {
  top: 0;
}
.open nav:before {

}

ul.menu {
  color: white;
}

ul.menu > li {
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.open ul.menu li {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.chevron {cursor: pointer;display: inline-block;position: absolute;left: 0;width: 32px;text-align: center;}

.chevron:before {
    border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-color: #fff;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    position: relative;
  top: 0.30em;
  left:-50px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    vertical-align: top;
  width: 16px;
  opacity: 1;
}



.submenu{
  display:none;
  opacity:0;
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  right: 40%;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: 10;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.submenu .submenu {
  right: 60vw;
}

.submenu .chevron:before {height: 10px;width: 10px;}

.item-opened ~ .submenu{
  opacity:1;
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 0;

}
.submenu li{
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding:0;
}

.submenu .submenu li{
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding:0;
}

article {
  padding: 24px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
.open article {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.92);
          transform: scale(0.92);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
}


/* Da bootstrap */
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%!important;
}
.position-relative {
    position: relative!important;
}
.align-items-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center!important;
  -ms-flex-align: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}
.justify-content-end {
  -webkit-box-pack: end!important;
  -ms-flex-pack: end!important;
  justify-content: flex-end!important;
}
.d-flex {
  display: -webkit-box!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-component">
  <div class="container position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
    <button class="menu-toggle">OPEN MENU</button>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div class="container position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end h-100">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#about-us">Lorem ipsum title 1</a>
          <span class="chevron"></span>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#history">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
              <span class="chevron"></span>
              <ul class="submenu">
                <li>Sub sub menu</li>
                <li>Sub sub menu</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>FIRST SUBMENU</li>
            <li>FIRST SUBMENU</li>
            <li>FIRST SUBMENU</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#capabilities">Lorem ipsum title 2</a>
          <span class="chevron"></span>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li> SECOND SUBMENU</li>
            <li> SECOND SUBMENU</li>
            <li> SECOND SUBMENU</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#sustainability">Lorem ipsum title 3</a>
          <span class="chevron"></span>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li> THIRD SUBMENU</li>
            <li> THIRD SUBMENU</li>
            <li> THIRD SUBMENU</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is to add an event handler for each click on **menuToggle**:

```
menuToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
..........
    item.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
```

Second, if you need to manage the third level it is reqiured to add a new event handler for the third level:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.submenu .chevron').forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.submenu .item-opened').forEach(function (openitem) {
            openitem.classList.remove('item-opened');
        });
        item.classList.toggle('item-opened');
    })
}, false);
```

The snippet:

```js
var nav = document.querySelector('.nav-component');
var menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
var menuItem = document.querySelector('.menu-item');
var itemOpened = document.querySelector('.item-opened');

menuToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
    nav.classList.toggle('open');
    document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item.item-opened').forEach(function (openitem) {
        openitem.classList.remove('item-opened');
    });
});
document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item > .chevron').forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item .item-opened').forEach(function (openitem) {
            openitem.classList.remove('item-opened');
        });
        item.classList.toggle('item-opened');
    })
}, false);

document.querySelectorAll('.submenu .chevron').forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.submenu .item-opened').forEach(function (openitem) {
            openitem.classList.remove('item-opened');
        });
        item.classList.toggle('item-opened');
    })
}, false);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

p {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin: 0 0 18px;
}

p span {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 2px 4px;
}

p span:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -12px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 0 0 3px;
}

p span:after {
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -6px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 6px 8px 6px;
    border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 44px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

button {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 24px;
    right: 20px;
    border: none;
    width: 150px;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
    zoom: 1.2;
}

button:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(burger.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

button:after {
    opacity: 1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 0;
    background: url(close.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
}

button:active {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2px);
    transform: translateY(2px);
}

button:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.open button {
    opacity: 1;
}

.open button:before {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
}

.open button:after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(360deg);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.4s 1s ease-out, opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.4s 1s ease-out, opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
}

nav {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: #776968;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.open nav {
    top: 0;
}

.open nav:before {
}

ul.menu {
    color: white;
}

ul.menu > li {
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

.open ul.menu li {
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 32px;
}

.chevron {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}

.chevron:before {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px 3px 0 0;
    border-color: #fff;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0.30em;
    left: -50px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 16px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.submenu {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 40%;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.submenu .submenu {
    right: 60vw;
}

.submenu .chevron:before {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}

.item-opened ~ .submenu {
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 0;
}

.submenu li {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0;
}

.submenu .submenu li {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0;
}

article {
    padding: 24px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 60px auto;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.open article {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.92);
    transform: scale(0.92);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
}

/* Da bootstrap */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.h-100 {
    height: 100% !important;
}

.position-relative {
    position: relative !important;
}

.align-items-center {
    -webkit-box-align: center !important;
    -ms-flex-align: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}

.justify-content-end {
    -webkit-box-pack: end !important;
    -ms-flex-pack: end !important;
    justify-content: flex-end !important;
}

.d-flex {
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-component">
    <div class="container position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
        <button class="menu-toggle">OPEN MENU</button>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <div class="container position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end h-100">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#about-us">Lorem ipsum title 1</a>
                    <span class="chevron"></span>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#history">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
                            <span class="chevron"></span>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li>Sub sub menu</li>
                                <li>Sub sub menu</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>FIRST MENU</li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#capabilities">Lorem ipsum title 2</a>
                    <span class="chevron"></span>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li>2222 Lorem ipsum dolor</li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#sustainability">Lorem ipsum title 3</a>
                    <span class="chevron"></span>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li>333333 Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a space in this selector `document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item.item-opened')` because `.item-opened` is a child of `.menu-item` so they need a space between them. When the classes are next to each other, it means that the same component has the two classes at the same time.

Check out the snipped code

```js
var nav = document.querySelector('.nav-component');
var menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
var menuItem = document.querySelector('.menu-item');
var itemOpened = document.querySelector('.item-opened');

menuToggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nav.classList.toggle('open');
  document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item.item-opened').forEach(openitem => {
    openitem.classList.remove('item-opened');
  });
  document.querySelectorAll('.chevron').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
      document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item .item-opened').forEach(openitem => {
        openitem.classList.remove('item-opened');
      });
      item.classList.toggle('item-opened');
    })
  })
}, false);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

a {text-decoration: none;color: #fff;}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0 0 18px;
}
p span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 2px 4px;
}
p span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -12px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 0 0 3px;
}
p span:after {
  content: '';
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -6px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 6px 8px 6px;
  border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}


h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  font-size:18px;
}

button {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 24px;
  right: 20px;
  border: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left:50%;
  right: 0;
  background: blue;
  zoom: 1.2;
}
button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(burger.svg) no-repeat;background-size: contain;
}
button:after {
  opacity: 1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 0;
  background: url(close.svg) no-repeat;background-size: contain;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
}
button:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(2px);
          transform: translateY(2px);
}
button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.open button {
  opacity: 1;
}
.open button:before {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}
.open button:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(360deg);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.4s 1s ease-out, opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.4s 1s ease-out, opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
}

nav {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #776968;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.open nav {
  top: 0;
}
.open nav:before {

}

ul.menu {
  color: white;
}

ul.menu > li {
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.open ul.menu li {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.chevron {cursor: pointer;display: inline-block;position: absolute;left: 0;width: 32px;text-align: center;}

.chevron:before {
    border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-color: #fff;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    position: relative;
  top: 0.30em;
  left:-50px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    vertical-align: top;
  width: 16px;
  opacity: 1;
}



.submenu{
  display:none;
  opacity:0;
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  right: 40%;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: 10;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.submenu .submenu {
  right: 60vw;
}

.submenu .chevron:before {height: 10px;width: 10px;}

.item-opened ~ .submenu{
  opacity:1;
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 0;

}
.submenu li{
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding:0;
}

.submenu .submenu li{
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding:0;
}

article {
  padding: 24px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
.open article {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.92);
          transform: scale(0.92);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
}


/* Da bootstrap */
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%!important;
}
.position-relative {
    position: relative!important;
}
.align-items-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center!important;
  -ms-flex-align: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}
.justify-content-end {
  -webkit-box-pack: end!important;
  -ms-flex-pack: end!important;
  justify-content: flex-end!important;
}
.d-flex {
  display: -webkit-box!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-component">
  <div class="container position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
    <button class="menu-toggle">OPEN MENU</button>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div class="container position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end h-100">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#about-us">Lorem ipsum title 1</a>
          <span class="chevron"></span>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#history">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
              <span class="chevron"></span>
              <ul class="submenu">
                <li>Sub sub menu</li>
                <li>Sub sub menu</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>FIRST MENU</li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#capabilities">Lorem ipsum title 2</a>
          <span class="chevron"></span>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>2222 Lorem ipsum dolor</li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#sustainability">Lorem ipsum title 3</a>
          <span class="chevron"></span>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>333333 Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: `.menu-item` and `.item-opened` are on the same element, though.  The `<li>` element.  So, actually, the code appears to be correct in that part: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13672822/2430549  You can also just *delete* `.item-opened` from the query and that "fixes" it, too.

Comment: Thanks for reply! If i use this JS, don't open children of submenu (another arrow "level 3"). How can i resolve it ? Thanks.

Comment: you cannot add **item.addEventListener('click', event => {** every time you click on menuToggle. This way you create a lot of same click event handler on the same element....

Answer (score 1):

I see that question already has answer, just guess my version also could be useful for someone

Open/close function below gives opportunity to work with different numbers of submenu's levels and don't write new listener for each new level:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.chevron').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
        item.closest('ul').querySelectorAll('.chevron.item-opened').forEach(openItem => {
            if (item == openItem) return false; // skip current item to toggle it after
            openItem.classList.remove('item-opened');
        });
        item.classList.toggle('item-opened');
    })
})
```

`item.closest('ul')` allow work with only current and lower levels of menu, e.g., if you click on second level menu it will close second and third levels but keep first level opened.

I changed your code a bit to show how it works with more levels of submenus:

```js
var nav = document.querySelector('.nav-component');
var menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');

menuToggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nav.classList.toggle('open');
  document.querySelectorAll('.chevron.item-opened').forEach(openitem => {
    openitem.classList.remove('item-opened');
  });
}, false);
document.querySelectorAll('.chevron').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    item.closest('ul').querySelectorAll('.chevron.item-opened').forEach(openitem => {
      if (item == openitem) return false;
      openitem.classList.remove('item-opened');
    });
    item.classList.toggle('item-opened');
  })
})
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

a {text-decoration: none;color: #fff;}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0 0 18px;
}
p span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 2px 4px;
}
p span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -12px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 0 0 3px;
}
p span:after {
  content: '';
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -6px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 6px 8px 6px;
  border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}


h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  font-size:18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

button {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 24px;
  right: 20px;
  border: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left:50%;
  right: 0;
  background: blue;
  zoom: 1.2;
}
button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(burger.svg) no-repeat;background-size: contain;
}
button:after {
  opacity: 1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 0;
  background: url(close.svg) no-repeat;background-size: contain;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
}
button:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(2px);
          transform: translateY(2px);
}
button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.open button {
  opacity: 1;
}
.open button:before {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}
.open button:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(360deg);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.4s 1s ease-out, opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.4s 1s ease-out, opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
}

nav {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #776968;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.open nav {
  top: 0;
}
.open nav:before {

}

ul.menu {
  color: white;
}

ul.menu > li {
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.open ul.menu li {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.chevron {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.chevron:before {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-color: #fff;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.30em;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 16px;
  opacity: 1;
}



.submenu{
  display:none;
  opacity:0;
  z-index: 10;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.submenu .submenu {
  right: 60vw;
}

.submenu .chevron:before {height: 10px;width: 10px;}

.item-opened ~ .submenu{
  opacity:1;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-right: 60px;
  display: block;
}
.submenu li{
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.submenu .submenu li{
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding:0;
}

article {
  padding: 24px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
.open article {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.92);
          transform: scale(0.92);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
}


/* Da bootstrap */
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%!important;
}
.position-relative {
    position: relative!important;
}
.align-items-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center!important;
  -ms-flex-align: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}
.justify-content-end {
  -webkit-box-pack: end!important;
  -ms-flex-pack: end!important;
  justify-content: flex-end!important;
}
.d-flex {
  display: -webkit-box!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-component">
  <div class="container position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
    <button class="menu-toggle">OPEN MENU</button>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div class="container position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end h-100">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#about-us">Title 1</a>
          <span class="chevron"></span>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#history">Title 1-1</a>
              <span class="chevron"></span>
              <ul class="submenu">
                <li>Title 1-1-1</li>
                <li>Title 1-1-2</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#history">Title 1-2</a>
              <span class="chevron"></span>
              <ul class="submenu">
                <li>Title 1-2-1</li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#history">Title 1-2-2</a>
                  <span class="chevron"></span>
                  <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>Title 1-2-2-1</li>
                    <li>Title 1-2-2-2</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#history">Title 1-2-3</a>
                  <span class="chevron"></span>
                  <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>Title 1-2-3-1</li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#history">Title 1-2-3-2</a>
                      <span class="chevron"></span>
                      <ul class="submenu">
                        <li>Title 1-2-3-2-1</li>
                        <li>Title 1-2-3-2-2</li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Title 1-3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#capabilities">Title 2</a>
          <span class="chevron"></span>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Title 2-1</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#sustainability">Title 3</a>
          <span class="chevron"></span>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Title 3-1</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the element with `classname` of `chevron`, but then hiding elements with `classname` of `menu-item`.  The right fix here would be just using the same classname.

[**Full Working Demo at JSBin**](https://jsbin.com/sojefevuni/1/edit?js,console,output)

```js
var nav = document.querySelector('.nav-component');
var menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
var menuItem = document.querySelector('.menu-item');
var itemOpened = document.querySelector('.item-opened');

menuToggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nav.classList.toggle('open');
  document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item.item-opened').forEach(openitem => {
    openitem.classList.remove('item-opened');
  });
  document.querySelectorAll('.chevron').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
      document.querySelectorAll('.chevron.item-opened').forEach(openitem => {
        openitem.classList.remove('item-opened');
      });
      item.classList.toggle('item-opened');
    })
  })
}, false);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

a {text-decoration: none;color: #fff;}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0 0 18px;
}
p span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 2px 4px;
}
p span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -12px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 0 0 3px;
}
p span:after {
  content: '';
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -6px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 6px 8px 6px;
  border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}


h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  font-size:18px;
}

button {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 24px;
  right: 20px;
  border: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left:50%;
  right: 0;
  background: blue;
  zoom: 1.2;
}
button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(burger.svg) no-repeat;background-size: contain;
}
button:after {
  opacity: 1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 0;
  background: url(close.svg) no-repeat;background-size: contain;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
}
button:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(2px);
          transform: translateY(2px);
}
button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.open button {
  opacity: 1;
}
.open button:before {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}
.open button:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(360deg);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.4s 1s ease-out, opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.4s 1s ease-out, opacity 0.4s 1s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s 1s ease-out;
}

nav {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #776968;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.open nav {
  top: 0;
}
.open nav:before {

}

ul.menu {
  color: white;
}

ul.menu > li {
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.open ul.menu li {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.chevron {cursor: pointer;display: inline-block;position: absolute;left: 0;width: 32px;text-align: center;}

.chevron:before {
    border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-color: #fff;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    position: relative;
  top: 0.30em;
  left:-50px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    vertical-align: top;
  width: 16px;
  opacity: 1;
}



.submenu{
  display:none;
  opacity:0;
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  right: 40%;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: 10;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.submenu .submenu {
  right: 60vw;
}

.submenu .chevron:before {height: 10px;width: 10px;}

.item-opened ~ .submenu{
  opacity:1;
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 0;

}
.submenu li{
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding:0;
}

.submenu .submenu li{
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding:0;
}

article {
  padding: 24px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
.open article {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.92);
          transform: scale(0.92);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.41s ease-out;
}


/* Da bootstrap */
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%!important;
}
.position-relative {
    position: relative!important;
}
.align-items-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center!important;
  -ms-flex-align: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}
.justify-content-end {
  -webkit-box-pack: end!important;
  -ms-flex-pack: end!important;
  justify-content: flex-end!important;
}
.d-flex {
  display: -webkit-box!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-component">
  <div class="container position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
    <button class="menu-toggle">OPEN MENU</button>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div class="container position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end h-100">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#about-us">Lorem ipsum title 1</a>
          <span class="chevron"></span>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#history">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
              <span class="chevron"></span>
              <ul class="submenu">
                <li>Sub sub menu</li>
                <li>Sub sub menu</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>FIRST MENU</li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#capabilities">Lorem ipsum title 2</a>
          <span class="chevron"></span>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>2222 Lorem ipsum dolor</li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#sustainability">Lorem ipsum title 3</a>
          <span class="chevron"></span>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>333333 Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```