# Get elements with one class but not another without iterating

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

In the following simple HTML, I would like to get **all elements with class1 but not with class2**.

```
<li class="class1 class2"></li>
<li class="class1 class3"></li>
<li class="class1 class4"></li>
```

By using `getElementsByClassName('class1')` we could get all elements and then possibly remove elements by [checking if a certain class exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class).

**Is there a better way to do this, without iterating?**

I found [this interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184562/javascript-how-to-get-elements-with-multiple-classes) about getting elements with multiple classes, so dare I ask: Is there something like this: `document.getElementsByClassName("class1 !class2")`?

P.S.: I don't want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you don't mind using the increasingly [compatible](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll) it's possible with just:

```
  var getClassOne = document.querySelectorAll( '.class1:not(.class2)' );
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/5tSGv/52/

Although without it, you'd have to iterate the className *somehow*

Comment: Thank you MackieeE, but the question is "Is there a better way to do this?", other than what you posted (which I described in my question)

Comment: I see! Apologies for skimming over the question too quickly - Added a fiddle with `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Thanks MackieeE. I don't mind using it at all. I would love to see more suggestions, though, but if they don't come up, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

So if the page is not having a dynamic generating div's, you can use `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Thanks! That's a useful hint.