# document.getElementsByClassName for multiple classes?

Tags: javascript

I'm a little stuck, please help.

```
<script>  
    var language = '#LanguageCode#-#CountryCode#';
    if(language === 'en-gb'){
      document.getElementsByClassName('apple')[0].innerHTML = '<img src="english-apple.svg"/>';    
      document.getElementsByClassName('android')[0].innerHTML = '<img src="english-android.svg"/>'; 

    } else if(language === 'nb-no'){
         document.getElementsByClassName('apple')[0].innerHTML = '<img src="norwegian-apple.svg"/>';  
         document.getElementsByClassName('android')[0].innerHTML = '<img src="norwegian-android.svg"/>'; 
    }   
</script>
```

This works a treat, but when I try to add another class to `document.getElementsByClassName`, it doesn't work.

Something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('apple bottomapple')[0].innerHTML = '<img src="english-apple.svg"/>';
```

In the other class I'm trying to add, there's an image with the same naming ***e.g. english-apple.svg***. I need both classes to run at the same time `if(language === 'nb-no')` is `true`.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - how to get elements with multiple classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184562/javascript-how-to-get-elements-with-multiple-classes)

Comment: Second class definitely exists and I've copied it 100x to make sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone put an answer here but now it's gone, wanted to thank them.

This worked for me:

[...document.querySelectorAll('.apple,.bottomapple')].map(x => x.innerHTML = '');

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Ok. So the problem here is this:

`document.getElementsByClassName('apple bottomapple')` will work for:

```
<div class="apple bottomapple"></div>
```

But it will **not** work for this:

```
<div class="apple"></div>
<div class="bottomapple"></div>
```

So you have one approach here that cames across my mind now. You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` method:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.apple, .bottomapple');
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].innerText = 'test ' + i;
}
```

```html
<div class="apple"></div>
<div class="bottomapple"></div>
```