# getElementsByClassName is space allowed?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get an element but the class name is `_2nlw _2nlv` it has a space in it.

Here is a image to show you that the class name is what it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/27fqh.png

The code im using is.
`var example = document.getElementsByClassName('_2nlw _2nlv').innerHTML;`

Its not working and im wondering if it has something to do with the empty space in the class name?
If so whats the solution?

Comment: A class in HTML cannot have a space in it, if it does, then those are 2 different classes

Comment: You should still look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method) and not call `.innerHTML` on the return. Also see comments on answers, you misspelled `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 4):

No such thing as a class with a space. That element has 2 classes and `getElementsByClassName` only searches for 1. You can use `document.querySelector('._2nlw._2nlv')` to match both.

Comment: there is nothing like `getElementByClassName`. It is `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Please check the first post again i put an image in there.

Comment: @AndersAndersson That's _two classes._ Read up on how CSS classes work. Ben's answer works in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch element**s** [having multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184562/javascript-how-to-get-elements-with-multiple-classes), leaving a space between  classes. In this purpose you just have to use `getElementsByClassName`:

```
var example = document.getElementsByClassName('class1 class2')[0].innerHTML;
```

Of course a class name can't have any space.

Comment: I find it ironic that you talk about using `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementByClassName` and then provide an example that uses the latter.

Comment: Interresting point, it's a bad copy / paste ahahah
Removed from the original question, so I did so !

Answer (score -5):

you can use jquery  with selector:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div class="_2nlw _2nlv">
text
</div>
<script>
$( "div._2nlw._2nlv" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );
</script>
```

here :[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/1b0hnb5c/10/)

**Use the element first and next the class css**

[Documentation Selector Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Your answer skips right over the fact that the OP has an invalid class name in the first place.

Comment: jQuery is just terribly unnecessary these days. It was great in 2011.