# How to I click the button in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

When I want to selenium click this code button , selenium write me this error

This is my code:

```
#LOGIN IN WEBSITE 
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get("http://class.apphafez.ir/")
    username_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='UserName']")
    password_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='Password']")
    username_input.send_keys(username_entry.get())
    password_input.send_keys(password_entry.get())
    button_go = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
    button_go.click()
    #GO CLASS
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser , 10)
    go_to_class = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH , ("//div[@class='btn btn-  palegreen enterClassBtn'"))))
    go_to_class.click()
```

this is site code :

```
<div class="databox-row   padding-10">
                    <button data-bind="attr: { 'data-weekscheduleId' :  Id}" style="width:100%" class="btn btn-palegreen enterClassBtn" data-weekscheduleid="320">"i want to ckick here"</button>
```

This is my program error :

```
  File "hafezlearn.py", line 33, in login_use
go_to_class = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH , ("//div[@class='btn btn-       palegreen enterClassBtn'")))) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
                </div>
```

Comment: this is my error:     File "hafezlearn.py", line 33, in login_use
    go_to_class = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH , ("//div[@class='btn btn-palegreen enterClassBtn'"))))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close enough. The value of the *class* attribute is **`btn btn-palegreen enterClassBtn`** but not `btn btn-       palegreen enterClassBtn` and you can't add extra spaces within the attribute value.

---

### Solution

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-palegreen.enterClassBtn[data-bind*='data-weekscheduleId']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-palegreen enterClassBtn' and text()='i want to ckick here'][contains(@data-bind, 'data-weekscheduleId')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple class names for css values are tough to handle. usually easiest way is to use a css selector:

```
button.btn.btn-palegreen.enterClassBtn
```

Specifically:

```
go_to_class = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR , ("button.btn.btn-palegreen.enterClassBtn"))))
```

See also [How to get elements with multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184562/how-to-get-elements-with-multiple-classes/7184581)