# jQuery not able to select element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick

I have a div class which is essentially a button that I'm trying to click using jQuery

```
<div class="tool-button refresh-button icon-tool-button" title="Refresh"><div class="button-outer"><span class="button-inner"><i class="fa fa-refresh text-blue"></i> </span></div></div>
```

Here is what I tried but the log confirms the length is 0 thus not selected, any suggestions?:

```
console.log($('.div.tool-button .refresh-button icon-tool-button:first'))

console.log($('.div.tool-button .refresh-button icon-tool-button'))
```

Comment: Notice you are missing `)`s

Comment: What's that `.` doing at the beginning of your selectors?

Comment: for class notation

Comment: but... that div doesn't have a div class.

Comment: `$(".div")` would match `<span class='div'>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get elements with multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184562/how-to-get-elements-with-multiple-classes)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your solutions, you trying to get:

```
<div class="tool-button">
  <div class="refresh-button">
    <div class="icon-tool-button"> // this
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you delete spaces on string, you can access your element.

The solution is

```
$(".tool-button.refresh-button.icon-tool-button")
```

Chaining selectors will query for elements that contain all of the selectors.

Detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59406548/11969749

Comment: Worked for me the spaces were the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Im glad to help you :). 

If you want a read a documentation: https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/ .

Answer (score 0):

You had multiple problems with the selector.

1. Remove . before `div` since its a tag not a class.
2. Remove the spaces between the classes, when there is space between them jquery is looking for element thats a child to the previous selector.

```js
console.log($('div.tool-button.refresh-button.icon-tool-button:first').length);

console.log($('div.tool-button.refresh-button.icon-tool-button').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tool-button refresh-button icon-tool-button" title="Refresh">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `click()` method

```js
const btn = $(".tool-button.refresh-button.icon-tool-button");
btn.click();
```

Do you want to select **first element**?

```js
const btn = $(".tool-button.refresh-button.icon-tool-button")[0];
btn.click();
```

Comment: This isn't my question

Comment: I gave you what you want, You have to glue the classes together, Dont use **space** between them