# Selecting multiple classes with querySelector

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname, queryselector

I want to manipulate classes by adding an eventlistener to two elements (.close and .overlay).

I tried to do this with the querySelector:

```
document.querySelector('.close, .overlay').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.menu').classList.remove('slide-in');
    document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.add('hide');
});
```

For some reason .overlay is ignored regardless if it comes before or after the .close class.

The above code only works when repeated for each class:

```
document.querySelector('.overlay').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.menu').classList.remove('slide-in');
    document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.add('hide');
});

document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.menu').classList.remove('slide-in');
    document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.add('hide');
});
```

Which seems excessive to me.

I found [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184562/how-to-get-elements-with-multiple-classes), which suggest using getElementsByClassName or querySelectorAll, but none of these seem to work for me.

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="open">Open menu</div>

<div class="menu">
    <p class="close">Close menu</p>
</div>

<div class="overlay hide"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
  display: block;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.menu .close {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.slide-in {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(40vw);
          transform: translateX(40vw);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 50;
}
```

Comment: Do the `.overlay` elements exist in the HTML at the point at which the JS runs? Also, without your ("*[mcve]*") HTML we can't really offer much of an explanation or insight into the problem; please: [edit] your question to include that HTML.

Comment: That's because `querySelector` only returns the first matching element. You need to use `querySelectorAll` to avoid code duplication, and iterate through the NodeList returned.

Comment: @DavidThomas as stated, when the querySelector is repeated for each class, everything works fine.

Comment: @Terry: I can't believe I missed that >.<

Comment: @DavidThomas It happens ;) I'll blame it on Monday and we don't talk about this ever again ;)

Comment: @Terry so am I supposed to use querySelectorAll?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. The linked duplicate contains the code you need to solve your problem.

Comment: You should use querySelectorAll. But it returns a nodelist which you need to iterate through to add your listeners. 
`document.querySelectorAll('.close, .overlay').forEach(el=>{
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {})})` -> to give you an idea