# How to include multiple css selector inside document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, css-selectors

I'm trying to hide multiple elements with a very small js code. It works fine if I include only one class, but when I include more than one class then it no longer works. Specifically, only the first selector inserted is always hidden. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I appreciate any help, thanks for any replies.

**This is what's working for me**

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.location.href.includes('?lost_pass=1')) {
    //Hide the element.
   document.querySelectorAll('.hide_login_title')[0].style.display = 'none';
   document.querySelectorAll('.hide_login_msg')[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

**This is what I am trying to do**

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.location.href.includes('?lost_pass=1')) {
    //Hide the element.
   document.querySelectorAll('.hide_login_title, .hide_login_msg')[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get elements with multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184562/how-to-get-elements-with-multiple-classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need loop through elements that querySelectorAll is returning. There are a couple options for how you could do this, one is the nodelist's built-in `.forEach()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach). It would look like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.location.href.includes('?lost_pass=1')) {
    //Hide the element.
   document.querySelectorAll('.hide_login_title, .hide_login_msg')
       .forEach((element) => element.style.display = 'none');
  }
};
```

Comment: Your solution works, thank you very much. I had already tried this solution and it was not working, evidently I was doing something wrong. Anyway that's okay.