# how to access buttons inside Mutiple div classes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of buttons inside multiple div classes. When any button in a particular div class is pressed I want wrong to pop up. I'm confused on how to access. I tried using `document.getElementsByClassName()` but this does not work. Is there another way? Here's what I currently have inside the body:

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='sections'>
    <div class='firstRow'>
      <button id="sect">cat1</button>
      <button id="sect">cat2</button>
      <button id="sect">cat3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("firstRow");
btnContainer[0].addEventListener("click", function () { 
  console.log("wrong"); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get elements with multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184562/how-to-get-elements-with-multiple-classes)

Comment: Do not use duplicate IDs `id="sect"`. ID is supposed to be unique. Use classes for your buttons instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the first object of *btnContainer*, which you did not define.

Also, the attribute [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) should be unique in a document, you can use [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead.

You can try using [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
to select all the element with the class (*firstRow*), and then loop through each button to add event listener to capture click events within that container.

**Demo:**

```html
<div class='container'>
        <div class='sections'>

            <div class='firstRow'>
                <button class="sect">cat1</button>
                <button class="sect">cat2</button>
                <button class="sect">cat3</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var btnContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".firstRow > .sect");
    btnContainer.forEach(sec => sec.addEventListener("click", function (){
      console.log('You have selected: ' + this.textContent); 
    })); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByClassName` method returns a set of elements with the  class name, not a single element. If you want to target the buttons inside the `.firstRow` div, you should use `getElementsByClassName("firstRow")[0]` or use `querySelector` instead.

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='sections'>
    <div class='firstRow'>
      <button class="sect">cat1</button>
      <button class="sect">cat2</button>
      <button class="sect">cat3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var btnContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("firstRow")[0];
  btnContainer.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("wrong"); 
  });
</script>
```

And don't forget to use class for the button as it not recommended to use the same id for multiple elements.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it via `getElementsByClassName`, see below:

```html
<div class='container'>
        <div class='sections'>

            <div class='firstRow'>
                <button id="sect">cat1</button>
                <button id="sect">cat2</button>
                <button id="sect">cat3</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("firstRow");
    for (let btn of btns) btn.addEventListener("click", function (){alert("wrong"); }); 
</script>
```

Or you could use `querySelectorAll(".sect")` instead if you prefer.